Henri Bergson (1859–1941). Is his theory of Absolute Knowledge and Method of Intuition a similar concept to Hegel's Absolute Truth?

Absolute knowledge is embedded in the evolution of life and can only
be grasped by the method of intuition. Thus, it is better to
investigate the origin and the evolution of intuition in order (i) to
understand how intuition makes a philosophy of life possible, and (ii)
to investigate what kind of philosophical method intuition is.
https://etd.lib.metu.edu.tr/upload/12618036/index.pdf


"Elan vital" can be interpreted as an inner drive, intuition, or a
sense of purpose that guides individuals throughout their lives.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89lan_vital

His belief in metaphysical logic driving the evolution of life reminds me Hegel's idea of a rational understanding of life through observation and study of human history in motion.

It seems more like Arthur Schopenhauer's concept of the conatus like will-to-live. Since absolute knowledge may be embedded in the evolution of life but may not be accessible like the Kantian thing-in-itself. Hegel's absolute World Spirit is more all-inclusive pantheistic-like simialar to Hilbert's slogan "we must know, we will know"...

Bergson's intuition seems totally opposed to Hegel's concept.
According to Bergson, every attempt to reduce the richness of the real to a fundamental idea is dommed to fail. For Bergson, traditional philosophical systems have all the same defect: trying to give a name to the absolute: either the Substance of Spinoza,  the Absolute of Schelling, the Idea of Hegel, ot the Will of Schopenhauer.
Bergson disliked "systematic" philosophy and general speculation and began each of his books with a particular problem.
The central concepts of Bergson's philosophy are intution: a kind of experience, and Bergson himself calls his thought “the true empiricism”, and duration, that means also time amd memory.
This means a point of view directed to the individual, that influenced also modernists and Proust, and in some sense also French existentialists.
Up to now, we would say that Bergson's philosophy has no connections with that of Hegel.
But there is a point where the two can be linked: Bergson's concept of creative evolution, taking inspiration from Darwin's theory (that of course was not available to Hegel) is a process phylosophy.
Bergson accepted evolution as a scientifically established fact. He proposed that the whole evolutionary process should be seen as the endurance of an élan vital (“vital impulse”) that is continually developing and generating new forms. Evolution, in short, is creative, not mechanistic.
This view can be compared to the evolution of Spirit in Hegel.

Thank you for a great explanation.
And for our almighty physicalists, I would like to point out that modern empirical research has no idea about élan vital (“vital impulse”) - the metaphysical driving force behind everything in our reality.
